# Can a prosecutor challenge a gubenatorial pre-emptive pardon?

Tags: united-states

In a state where the governor has power ([Do (any) US State Governors have legal authority to preemptively pardon persons of a state crime?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/21688/do-any-us-state-governors-have-legal-authority-to-preemptively-pardon-persons)) to pardon a capital crime **before** prosecution, does a prosecutor who learns of the governor's intent to pardon have any way to force prosecution?

Comment: By “force prosecution”, do you mean “overrule their power of pardon”, or “force a trial which, even if it resulted in a conviction, would have no legal effect”?

Comment: I meant force a trial, even if it results in a conviction. The point is to achieve a conviction.

Comment: There are some states where the Governor does not have the sole right to issue a pardon (For example Texas, which must be voted on by the Pardon and Parole board and then signed by the Governor).  It would follow thusly that this answer depends on a review of every state constitution and the limits of the pardoning power.  As a general rule, this would be a no, as most states copy the U.S. Constitution, where the Presidential Pardons cannot be challenged save for voting out of office or impeachment.  There's a reason why most presidents issue pardons while they are lame ducks.

Comment: The trivial answer is that when the Governor might pardon someone who hasn't been convicted of something that a prosecutor can commence a criminal case which the prosecutor may or may not be able to conclude with a verdict on the merits prior to the Governor's action if the Governor does act. The fact that the Governor is thinking about pardoning someone doesn't prevent a prosecutor from commencing a criminal case. But if the Governor does pardon that person before there is a verdict, the effort to prosecute the case was a waste of time and money. It isn't clear that this is what was asked.

Answer (score 4):

### There is no recourse

The Pardon results in the pardoned person having no liability for the act, no matter if it was a crime or not, and no matter whether the pardon pre-dates a prosecution. There is no legal or political way to appeal a pardon. There isn't even a way to *take back* a pardon! As a result, the prosecutor or the next governor can do nothing.